# Problem returning back to Scene from another Scene Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, scene

I am new to Phaser and I want to get some help or explanation associated with my problem.

So, I wanted to switch the scene to the next scene when my character reaches a certain point. In this case the end point of the world bounds (scene).

I wrote this in `update()`:

```
//sceneA
if(postava.x < 0)
{ 
    this.scene.switch("rozcestnikScena");
}
```

This block of code works great and switches to the next scene.

Then I wrote in the second scene in `update()`:

```
//sceneB
if(postava.x > 800)
{
    this.scene.switch("uvodniScena");
}
```

Now, when it switches to the first scene (sceneA), my character appears in a running loop and cannot be controlled and runs to the world bounds and the scene stays the same.

I read many tutorials, but I can't figure out why the character cannot be controlled and acts on its own.

Any help is much appreciated!

**More code:**

**1.Scene**

```
let zeme;
let postava;
let klavesnice;
let auto;
let keyA;
let keyW;
let keyS;
let keyD;

class JSScenaPlay extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("uvodniScena");
    }

    create() {

        this.gzDialog.setText("Ah heck, my car has broken down. I need to go to a nearby town and find somebody who can help.");
        this.background = this.add.image(0, 0, "pozadiObloha");
        this.background.setOrigin(0, 0);

        zeme = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        zeme.create(config.width / 2, 675, "zeme").refreshBody();

        postava = this.physics.add.sprite(20, 556, "postava");
        postava.setBounce(0.1);
        postava.setDepth(5);

        auto = this.physics.add.image(config.width / 2 + 325, 562, "auto");
        auto.setScale(1.5);
        auto.setDepth(1);

        this.anims.create({
                key: "right",
                frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("postava", { start: 5, end: 8 }),
                frameRate: 10,
                repeat: -1
            });

        this.anims.create({
                key: "turn",
                frames: [{ key: "postava", frame: 4 }],
                frameRate: 20
            });

        this.anims.create({
                key: "left",
                frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("postava", { start: 0, end: 3 }),
                frameRate: 10,
                repeat: -1
            });

        postava.body.setGravityY(50);

        this.physics.add.collider(postava, zeme);

        this.physics.add.collider(auto, zeme);
        this.physics.add.collider(postava, auto, diaOkno, null, this);
        auto.setPushable(false);

        klavesnice = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        function diaOkno(postava, auto) {
            postava.anims.play("turn");
            this.gzDialog.visible;
            this.gzDialog.setText("I need to find some car mechanic to repair the engine.");
        }

        keyA = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
        keyS = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
        keyD = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
        keyW = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);
    }

    update() {
        //pohyb doleva
        if (keyA.isDown || klavesnice.left.isDown) {
            postava.setVelocityX(-100);
            postava.anims.play("left", true);
        }
        //pohyb doprava
        else if (keyD.isDown || klavesnice.right.isDown) {
            postava.setVelocityX(100);
            postava.anims.play("right", true);
        }
        else {
            postava.setVelocityX(0);
            postava.anims.play("turn");
        }

        //skok
        if (keyW.isDown && postava.body.touching.down || klavesnice.up.isDown && postava.body.touching.down) {
            postava.setVelocityY(-250);
        }

        if (postava.x < 0) {
            this.scene.switch("rozcestnikScena");
        }
    }
}
```

**2.Scene**

```
class JSScenaPlayRozcestnik extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("rozcestnikScena");
    }

    create() {

        this.background = this.add.image(0, 0, "pozadiObloha");
        this.background.setOrigin(0, 0);

        zeme = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

        zeme.create(config.width / 2, 675, "zeme").refreshBody();

        postava = this.physics.add.sprite(800, 556, "postava");

        postava.setBounce(0.1);

        postava.setDepth(5);

        klavesnice = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        this.physics.add.collider(postava, zeme);

        this.anims.create({
                key: "right",
                frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("postava", { start: 5, end: 8 }),
                frameRate: 10,
                repeat: -1
            });

        this.anims.create({
                key: "turn",
                frames: [{ key: "postava", frame: 4 }],
                frameRate: 20
            });

        this.anims.create({
                key: "left",
                frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("postava", { start: 0, end: 3 }),
                frameRate: 10,
                repeat: -1
            });

        postava.body.setGravityY(50);
    }
    update() {
        //pohyb doleva
        if (keyA.isDown || klavesnice.left.isDown) {
            postava.setVelocityX(-100);
            postava.anims.play("left", true);
        }
        //pohyb doprava
        else if (keyD.isDown || klavesnice.right.isDown) {
            postava.setVelocityX(100);
            postava.anims.play("right", true);
        }
        else {
            postava.setVelocityX(0);
            postava.anims.play("turn");
        }

        //skok
        if (keyW.isDown && postava.body.touching.down || klavesnice.up.isDown && postava.body.touching.down) {
            postava.setVelocityY(-250);
        }

        //zavření dialogového okna
        if (this.gzDialog.visible) {
            this.physics.pause();
            postava.anims.play("right");

            if (klavesnice.space.isDown) {
                this.gzDialog.display(false);
                this.physics.resume();
            }
        }

        if (postava.x > 800) {
            this.scene.switch("uvodniScena");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more code? since this code pieces and question don't explain the issue in enough detail.

Comment: I have added additional code from scenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is when you switch back, the *"player"* is stil over *the magic switch line* (`800px`).

You would onl have to move the player before switching the scene, so that when you come back the switch is not triggered again and again in a loop.

**Here is a optimized, small demo:**
*here the player will moved behind the switch line before switching the scene.

(I used inheritance to avoid code duplication)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class PlayerScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    create() {
        let player = this.add.rectangle(10, 50, 20, 20, 0xffffff)
            .setOrigin(0);
       
        this.physics.add.existing(player);
        this.player = player.body;
        this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        
        let floor = this.add.rectangle(0, config.height, config.width, 10, 0xffffff)
            .setOrigin(0,1);
        
        this.physics.add.existing(floor, true);
        
        this.physics.add.collider(player, floor);
        
        this.keys = {
            ...this.input.keyboard.addKeys("W,A,S,D"),
            ...this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()
        };
    }

    update() {
        let speed = 150;
        this.player.setVelocityX(0);
        if (this.keys.A.isDown || this.keys.left.isDown) {
            this.player.setVelocityX(-speed);
        } else if (this.keys.D.isDown || this.keys.right.isDown) {
            this.player.setVelocityX(speed);
        }

        if (  this.player.touching.down &&(this.keys.W.isDown || this.keys.up.isDown)) {
            this.player.setVelocityY(-speed);
        } 
    }
}

class FirstScene extends PlayerScene {
    constructor() {
        super('FirstScene');
    }

    create() {
        super.create();
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'Scene 1\nUse WASD to move the "player"')
            .setOrigin(0)
            
        this.add.line(0, 0, 400, 0, 400, config.height, 0xffffff)
            .setOrigin(0);
    }
    
    update(){
        super.update();
        if(this.player.x > 400){
            this.scene.switch('SecondScene');
            this.player.x -= 30;
        }
    }
}

class SecondScene extends PlayerScene {
    constructor() {
        super('SecondScene');
    }

    create() {
        super.create();
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'Scene 2\nUse WASD to move the "player"')
            .setOrigin(0);
            
        this.add.line(0, 0, 10, 0, 10, config.height, 0xffffff)
            .setOrigin(0);
       
        this.player.x = 30;
    }
    
    update(){
        super.update();
        if(this.player.x < 10 ){
            this.player.x += 30;
            this.scene.switch('FirstScene');
        }
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: { default: 'arcade', 
        arcade: {
            debug: true,
            gravity: { y: 300 }
        }
    },
    scene: [FirstScene, SecondScene]
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have used your code this.player.x += 30 and it didn't help. Player is running and cannot be controlled. :(

Comment: @Anyn you have to adapt the demo, to fit your code. the questions is does my demo run more or less as you want your code to work. if so, adapt the parts correctly. like you might have missed that `this.player = player.body` part or some other minor detail. my code is pretty short but almost every line is essential.  `this.player.x+=30` is needed move scene 1 to 2 and something like `this.player.x-=30` is neede for the way back. btw 30 is judt andemo number depending on your sizes you might smaller or bigger numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have adapted the code and now it works great. Only 1 thing is missing, how to make the player jump from the ground only once and he would't jump infinitely in the air?

Comment: @Anyn I updated my answer, with this extra feature. You can also check the official [_first game_ demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/games/firstgame/part10) for full plattformer movement. :)

Comment: @Anyn if my answer answered your question please consider, accepting it(with the green checkmark), or if I missed something let me know. thank you

Comment: I used the jumping code and I got this message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'down')

Comment: @Anyn this error means that a `key` is not defined.  Check if the keys you created are the same as in my demo Code _( `this.keys = {...}` , in the custom `PlayerScene` class)_. Try to copy the exactly, and only removes parts you don't need, but avoid deleting too much.

Comment: thank you very much for all of those examples, everything works great :)